# jquery mobile not working on IE but ok with other browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have set up a jQuery mobile page, for some reason, it is not working on some version of IE , but working ok with chomp or firefox. I am not sure is it the head part or the body part code wrong,. example link is:

http://www.xuanyinwen.com/test9.html

code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 


    <title>RE/MAX Leaders Licensed Real Estate Agent (REAA 2008)</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://computersforpeople.info/websites/scripts/jquery/lib/klass.min.js"></script>  
    <link href="http://computersforpeople.info/websites/scripts/jquery/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://computersforpeople.info/websites/scripts/jquery/code.photoswipe-3.0.5.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe)
        {
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#gallery a").photoSwipe(
                {
                    enableMouseWheel: false,
                    enableKeyboard: false
                });

                $("#gallery a:first").click();
            });
        }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));





</script>




<script type="text/javascript">

$('a').live('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( !$this.attr('rel') || $this.attr('rel') != 'external' )
        $(document.getElementById( $this.attr('href') )).remove();
});


</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {font-size: large}
-->
</style>
</head> 

<body> 


<div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Back" >
<div data-role="header" >
        <h1 style="white-space:normal"></h1>
        <div align="center"> 
</div>

  </div>
  <ul  data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false">
        <li><a href="/users/337/properties">Properties</a></li>

                <ul data-role="listview"  data-filter="false" id="test-more">

                          <table>



    <li ><a href="/users/337/properties/56920">
<img src="/media/2013/01/23/015609_48016.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=80x60&s=b439018cf179642b"/>           

<h3>Karori, 28A Duthie Street</h3>
                <p>Tender</p>
            </a></li>  









    <li ><a href="/users/337/properties/56948">
<img src="/media/2013/01/23/020339_47985.jpg?m=resize&o[geometry]=80x60&s=4252c33b91339630"/>           

<h3>Miramar, 1/50 Darlington Road</h3>
                <p>Tender</p>
            </a></li>  


</table>

    </ul>
    <br />



<li><a href="#contact_us" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="left" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" id="contact">Contact Kahn May</a></li>


</ul>

    <div data-role="footer" align="center">

    <h6 style="font-size: 55%;font-family:calibri">
  RE/MAX Leaders Real Estate (1987) Ltd Licensed Under REAA 2008</h6>
    </div>
    <!-- /footer -->

    </div>  

<!-- /page -->

<div data-role="page" id="contact_us" data-title="Contact Us">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1></h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <p class="style1"><strong>Kahn May</strong></p>
                <p><a href="tel:021 931 381">021 931 381</a><br>
                  <br>
                  <a href="mailto:kmay@leaders.co.nz">kmay@leaders.co.nz</a></p>
  </div>
            <div data-role="footer">

            </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code - an element with id=gallery

Answer (score 0):

because the content code got  tab, it make the page not working on IE.